# NHibernate linq match against a collection of search values

Tags: .net, nhibernate, hql, linq-to-nhibernate

I am using linq to nhibernate to search against entity names and its aliases.

```
class Entity
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string[] Aliases { get; set; }
}

enityQueryable.Where(x =>
    x.Name.StartsWith(searchParam) ||
    x.Aliases.Any(a => a.StartsWith(searchParam)));
```

That part works fine.

I now have a requirement to match against a list of possible search terms. I can do the query in linq which works fine however Nhibernate, as expected, wasn't able to translate it into Hql.

```
enityQueryable.Where(x => MatchOnNameOrAlias(x));

private bool MatchOnNameOrAlias(Entity e, string[] searchTerms)
{
    foreach (var searchTerm in searchTerms)
    {
        if (e.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (e.Aliases.Any(a => a.StartsWith(companySearchTerm)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I started to look at using a `LinqToHqlGenerator`, the implementation was relativly straight forward and on first inspection appeared to work however it only works the first time. Subsequent calls reuse the same collection of search parameters.

```
public class MatchesAnySearchTermGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public MatchesAnySearchTermGenerator()
    {
        SupportedMethods = new[] { ReflectionHelper.GetMethod(() => SearchLinqExtensions.MatchesAnySearchTerm(null, null)) };
    }

    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, Expression targetObject, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments,             HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        var likes = ((IEnumerable<string>)((ConstantExpression) arguments[1]).Value).ToArray();

        HqlBooleanExpression lastBooleanExpression = CreateHqlLike(treeBuilder, visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(), likes[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < likes.Length; i++)
        {
            lastBooleanExpression = treeBuilder.BooleanOr(lastBooleanExpression,
                CreateHqlLike(treeBuilder, visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(), likes[i]));
        }
        return lastBooleanExpression;
    }

    private HqlLike CreateHqlLike(HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, HqlExpression nameExpression, string like)
    {
        return treeBuilder.Like(nameExpression, treeBuilder.Constant(like + '%'));
    }
}
```

This appears to be a known issue.

[StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951400/nhibernate-hql-generator-caching-expression)

[NHibernate Jira Issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2658)

So without having to revert to using NHibernate directly to perform the query and maintaining the dependency on IQueryable in my code base. Is there an alternative to my first query that Nhibernate will support or can I structure the HqlGenerator such that it will not cache the first list of search terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that meets my needs. It does not use the Hql Generator approach. Instead it builds the linq query such that Nhibernate can convert it to Hql itself. The following links helped with this, the second is actually a refinement of the first if you read the comments.

[NHibernate Linq provider: dynamic filtering using lambda expressions](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-linq-dynamic-filtering-lambda-expressions)

[Dynamically built LINQ query no longer working in NH3.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nhusers/ntoKI71PWdE/jIwCSLtnOqEJ)

I was able to do the following:

```
Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> predicate = null;

predicate = searchTerms.Aggregate(predicate, (current, source1) => current == null ? NameStartsWith(source1) : current.Or(NameStartsWith(source1)));

enityQueryable.Where(predicate);

private static Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> NameStartsWith(string searchTerm)
{
    return p => p.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(searchTerm) || p.Aliases.Any(x => x.StartsWith(searchTerm));
}
```

Using the approach mentioned in the two links:

```
static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var adaptedExpr2Body = ReplacingExpressionTreeVisitor.Replace(
            expr2.Parameters[0],
            expr1.Parameters[0],

            expr2.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, adaptedExpr2Body),
            expr1.Parameters);
    }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var adaptedExpr2Body = ReplacingExpressionTreeVisitor.Replace(
            expr2.Parameters[0],
            expr1.Parameters[0],

            expr2.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, adaptedExpr2Body),
            expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```